# Missing Physics Tab? [Blender 2.78]

Tags: physics

I'm just wondering if anyone else is missing the options in the physics tab of their Blender program with the new 2.78? It was released yesterday. I knew I should have waited before downloading it...

I've tried scrolling up, but there's absolutely nothing there. At all.

Ideas? Help? Anything?

Comment: Some screenshots of Properties editor ? Do you have any object selected (I couldn't resist of asking) ? How many tabs are avaible there ?

Comment: scrolling up... what? there...where? physics tab is the last on the right in the properties editor... sorry, I have opengl 1.4 at home, can't install 2.7/2.8 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an object selected, by I guess the program didn't download properly the first, third, or fifth time - by sixth reinstall, physics options returned.

Thanks everyone!